# Error in updating my table

Tags: java, ms-access, sql-update

I am having an error when updating my records in the takenOutTbl (only has a few records). Any help would be highly appreciated. This is the update code:

```
fine = overdueDays * 10; //the fine is calculated by multiplying the number of overdue days by the 10
            simpleUpdate("update takenOutTbl set Random Calculations = Random Calculations " + fine);
```

it is connected to this method:

```
public static void simpleUpdate(String update) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Connection connection = dc.DatabaseConnection(); //a connection to the database is established
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(update); //the conenction is used to prepare the update statement which was sent to this method
        statement.executeUpdate();//the statement is executed
        statement.close(); //the prepared statement is closed
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: the database was not updated. Please try again." );
        System.err.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and the error message I receive is this:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: RANDOM
```

Comment: The error message should give the issue way. It attempted to use "RANDOM" as an identifier, not "RANDOM CALCULATIONS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your query as follows:

```
"update takenOutTbl set [Random Calculations] = [Random Calculations] + " + fine
```

Because of the space in your column name, you have to help out MS Access a little bit and indicate that `Random Calculations` is one column. You do this by enclosing the column name in brackets.

Also, your query lacked a `+` at the end, so I've added that in my example above as well.

Comment: Thanks, although if I do that I now receive this error:
"unexpected token: 40"

Comment: You have added the `+` to the end of your query right?